# Head/Vision Tracking

Tags: editing, youtube, motion

At the 1:20 mark of this video, the author incorporates a line of sight marker to track the players line of vision. Any suggestions on how he did this? What software he might have used, etc?

I want to try and reproduce in some of my own videos.

Thank you.

Comment: Ask Howard Chang, the guy who's video it is. I'm sure he'd tell you.

Comment: Thanks, already tried. No reply. Hard to get messages through on youTube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally heard back from the Author:

> "I use Adobe After Effects for the graphics in all my videos.  The head tracker is basically a solid line with transparency set to about 50%.  The rotation point on the line is moved to one end of the line, and then you place it on the player's head and set it to follow a null point.  In some of the cases, I had to animate the line manually.  It does take a bit of time, but it definitely highlights the point.  Let me know if you need any other help.  Good luck!"

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really look like it is actually being tracked.  It looks like a manual overlay of a line on to it based on the head movement.  It really doesn't look particularly accurate either from what I can tell.  Something like Adobe After Effects (paid) or Black Magic's Fusion (free) can easily be used to accomplish this, though they do both have a learning curve.